# Is there Dart VM available?

Tags: dart, runtime, interpreter, vm-implementation

Just read news that Google had announced an early preview of the new web programming language Dart. The documentation on the [dartlang.org](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/technical-overview/index.html) states:

> You will be able to run Dart code in several ways:
>
> - Translate Dart code to JavaScript that can run in any modern browser:
>     Chrome, Safari 5+, and Firefox 4+ (more browser support coming
>     shortly).
> - Execute Dart code directly in a VM on the server side
> - Use Dartboard to write, modify, and execute small Dart programs
>     within any browser window

And I'm curious is there already VM available to run Dart code? Can't find it anyway, maybe it is available through some beta program?

Comment: I'm extremely bummed out that the only way to test Dart is by compiling it to Javascript (meh) or use the REPL for simple cheesy one liners. We need an easier way to try the language out. Lower the barrier of entry Google!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A pre-built binary of the Dart VM is available in the [Dart SDK](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/sdk/). Alternatively, you can [checkout the source](https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/GettingTheSource?tm=4) to the whole Dart project, which includes the VM.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. One note - it has to be compiled from sources, seems that no prebuilt binaries are available at the moment.

Comment: try.dartlang.org is deprecated and will be removed or replaced.

Comment: Replace by DartEditor and Dartium (Chromium + DartVM): http://www.dartlang.org/docs/editor/ & http://www.dartlang.org/dartium/

Answer (score 7):

Dartium, Chromium with a Dart VM, is now available.

http://www.dartlang.org/dartium/

Answer (score 1):

You can download precompiled binary runtime for Windows, Linux and Mac from [Dart Force](http://www.dartforce.com/dev/index.html). Another way is to run node.js-style HTTP server using [Fling](http://dartwatch.com/index.php/2011/10/fling-a-dart/).